# Create Pull Request From Upstream Repo in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I am using BitBucket to host my project.

I have a project with a fork - I develop niche functionality in that fork and core functionality in the main upstream repository. Whenever I create some functionality in the fork that I want in the core I can create a pull request and merge. However I can't seem to be able to create a pull request going from the upstream repo to my downstream one.

Do you know if this functionality is available in BitBucket?

Comment: Usually, you would simply pull from the upstream repository, merge those changes in and then push into your forked repository.

Comment: I take your point but I could do the exact same for the opposite way. I suppose the reasoning behind it is that you want the code to go through some kind of review process. Then again if its already in the 'core' repo its already been through a review.

Answer (score 0):

Not BitBucket per se, but Git does.

## The usual way

Quoting [@Poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke)'s comment:

> Usually, you would simply pull from the upstream repository, merge
>   those changes in and then push into your forked repository.

## Frowned upon - set up a pair of remotes

When you fork/clone, you usually set up a remote as well, that points to that other repository. This is why one repository acts as an "upstream" for the other. Of course, you may have two "upstreams", if you wish. You just define "two-way" remotes (fork has remote "main", main gets remote "fork").

This, however, is rather frowned upon (*discouraged may be a word you may hear as well, and sometimes even forbidden I'd expect*) due to flow with which one often works with Git. 
Granted, there's more than one way to skin a cat, but folks usually like their main repo being somewhat EXTRAordinary, that is without having remotes. There are also voices who will tell you that having that window open will mean it will be used and everybody will be pushing/pulling to everybody, which is bloody chaos and you can't know what is what anymore.

Nevertheless, you can do it so heed the voices or pay them no mind, whichever floats your boat. ;-)

Let me know if you'd like to know how to set remote.